# How do I configre Kerberos for Web Application in IIS windows server 2012?

Tags: kerberos, ntlm, spring-security-kerberos, kerberos-delegation, mit-kerberos

My scenario:
I have a sample website hosted on IIS windows 2012 server. When I browse the website it should prompt for credentials of the the Active Directory. I have tried using 'Windows Authentication' it is working fine, It is using NTLM for Windows Authentication

How can I use Kerberos for login to the website instead of NTLM

I have tried the steps in thelink, but it is not working
https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/06/04/kerberos-web-application-configuration/

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below link has the detailed procedure for the above query

http://woshub.com/configuring-kerberos-authentication-on-iis-website/